# Set the AWS S3 Key header in the URI only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-camel

I have a rest api using apache camel. When I hit a post request on a route, it should get a file from S3. I am sending json data(filename, bucketName, accesskey, secretkey, region) in order to extract the file from s3. Here is the code for that ->

```
public static class HelloRoute extends RouteBuilder {
       
        @Override
        public void configure() {
            rest("/")
                .post("file-from-s3")
                    .route()
                    .setHeader(AWS2S3Constants.KEY, constant("filename"))
                    .to("aws2-s3://bucketnameaccessKey=INSERT&secretKey=INSERT&region=INSERT&operation=getObject")
                    .to("file:/tmp/")
```

The issue is that I don't want the `.setHeader(AWS2S3Constants.KEY, constant("filename"))`
part. Is there a way to remove that and put an alternate to that in the URI itself. I tried something like this ->

```
public static class HelloRoute extends RouteBuilder {
       
        @Override
        public void configure() {
            rest("/")
                .post("file-from-s3")
                    .route()                 
                    .to("aws2-s3://bucketnameaccessKey=INSERT&secretKey=INSERT&region=INSERT&filename=hello.txt&operation=getObject")
                    .to("file:/tmp/")
```

But this is giving me an error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AWS S3 Key header missing.`. Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai ```Unknown parameters=[{camel.component.aws2-s3.key-name=hello.txt}]``` getting this as an error

Answer (score 0):

> Sometimes build an AWS Request can be complex, because of multiple options. We introduce the possibility to use a POJO as body.

Take a look at: https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/aws2-s3-component.html#_using_a_pojo_as_body

Comment: Can you look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62763173/how-to-do-custom-error-handling-in-an-apache-camel-rest-api